# How to create a vector field in Dall-E 3?

Tags: dall-e

I want to create an image that looks like below.

[image]

After failed attempts at my own description, I used chatgpt to generate a prompt for me:

> The image is a simple two-dimensional drawing featuring a series of blue lines on a white background. These lines are arranged in a pattern that suggests they are creating an abstract representation of swirling or flowing movement, almost like water in a whirlpool or strands of hair being tousled by the wind. The lines are uniform in color and thickness, and there is no shading or gradient, giving the drawing a flat, graphic quality. The pattern does not form any recognizable shape or figure; it is purely abstract. The lines vary in length but are mostly short dashes, with the direction of the lines changing to create the overall swirling pattern.

[image]

The rendered image by dall-e doesn't even come close to the original image. And many attempts later, I am not getting anywhere.

Anyone has any ideas on how to generate some random vectorfield? The details of flow don't matter because just want to use it as background.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you should not be using Dall-E or any generic text to image AI for. You can get results much quicker and easier by using a [tool that generates vector fields](https://www.geogebra.org/m/QPE4PaDZ). If you want to add unnecessary AI to the process, you can use ChatGPT to generate an equation. Here's what I got:

[image: Vx= sinx cosy; Vy = cosx siny]

(This is what ChatGPT thinks is a complicated and interesting equation apparently.)

If you wanted to apply more unnecessary AI, you could use an AI that applies textures to an image, such as [Fotor](https://www.fotor.com/features/ai-filter/). I'm not sure what results you'll get, or if it will even look like a vector field at that point.

Comment: I agree! I managed to get it to work easily using an R package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648480/calculate-and-plot-vector-field-of-an-arbitrary-rasterlayer

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get what I wanted using this R package [ggquiver](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/ggquiver) based on the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648480/calculate-and-plot-vector-field-of-an-arbitrary-rasterlayer).

From a gradient

[image]

to a vector field

[image]

Here is the code if interested:

```
library(ggplot2)
# remotes::install_github("mitchelloharawild/ggquiver")
library(ggquiver)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

#' @description Read a JPG and export a vectorfield
#' @param path Path to a jpg or png
#' @param aggregate Density of vectors?
#' @param size Size of arrows
#' @param dpi Output dpi
#' @param output Output file name and path if needed
#'
vf <- function(path, aggregate = 50, size = 1.5, dpi = 96, output = NULL) {
    rast <- raster::raster(path)

    # Add a fake arbitrary projection otherwise "terrain()" doesn't work:
    projection(rast) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"

    names(rast) <- "z"
    quiv <- aggregate(rast, aggregate)
    terr <- terrain(quiv, opt = c("slope", "aspect"))
    quiv$u <- terr$slope[] * sin(terr$aspect[])
    quiv$v <- terr$slope[] * cos(terr$aspect[])
    quiv_df <- as.data.frame(quiv, xy = TRUE)
    rast_df <- as.data.frame(rast, xy = TRUE)

    p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
        # geom_raster(data = rast_df, na.rm = TRUE) +
        geom_quiver(data = quiv_df, aes(u = u, v = v), vecsize = size) +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(
            axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            legend.position = "none",
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            plot.background = element_blank()
        )

    if (is.null(output)) {
        d <- dirname(path)
        fname <- basename(path)
        ext <- paste0(".", tools::file_ext(fname))
        fname <- sub(ext, "", fname, fixed = TRUE)
        output <- file.path(d, paste0(fname, "-", aggregate, "-", size, ".png"))
    }

    ggsave(output, p, width = dim(rast)[2], height = dim(rast)[1], dpi = dpi, units = "px")
}
```

Run `vf(path = "input.jpg")` and it exports a png to the same directory.

That took me over an hour to install, rewrite and tweak. And that is considering the fact that I understand R code. I was hoping the AI would save me some time, but not today.